# StyleGAN image generation doesn't work, TensorFlow doesn't see GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu

After reinstalling [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), I cannot generate images anymore using a StyleGAN agent. The error message I get is `InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation Gs_1/_Run/Gs/latents_in: {{node Gs_1/_Run/Gs/latents_in}}was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.`

I have CUDA 10.1 and my driver version is 418.87. The YAML file for the Conda environment is available [here](https://gist.github.com/albusdemens/3aadd9f2586095ce0963dd5e0d380bf0). I installed tensorflow-gpu==1.14 using pip.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/albusdemens/c3389936915462c6a991ebdedb129900) you can find the Jupyter Notebook document I'm using to generate the images.

If I check the available resources as recommended using the commands

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I get the answer

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 7185754797200004029
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 18095173531080603805
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 10470458648887235209
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because TensorFlow is looking for `GPU:0` to assign a device for an operation when the name of your graphical unit is actually `XLA_GPU:0`.

You could try to use soft placement when opening your session, so that TensorFlow uses any existing GPU (or any other supported devices if unavailable) when running:

```
#  using allow_soft_placement=True
se = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry about this! Have you tried downgrading TensorFlow to an older version to check whether the problem comes from this?

Comment: I tried using tensorfflow-gpu==1.12 but that didn't help.

Comment: Sorry for you! Reading a bunch of things about this issue now, have you also tried installing cuDNN (https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have CuDNN installed. I just checked the steps recommended in https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html and the package is correctly installed.

Comment: Ok! If you're using a conda environment, some people from GitHub suggest uninstalling the pip version of TensorFlow (with `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu`), and then installing the conda one instead (with `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`). Have you tried this as well?

Comment: I resintalled tensorflow-gpu using conda, and now things are fine! Thanks heaps!

Comment: Adding 'allow_soft_placement': 1 to tf_config in train.py worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For running stylegan in Colab:

Go to *dnnlib/tflib/tfutil.py* and change

```
config_proto = tf.ConfigProto()
```

to

```
config_proto = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True).
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Comment: it is related to tf.session(...) configurtion and causes tensorflow uses any existing GPU.